# How to loop through field deltas of an object?

Tags: entities, 8

In Drupal 7 I loaded the node/entity I want with node_load / entity_load and, if necessary, then I took a field with multiple deltas and take the value I wanted with a foreach loop.

In Drupal 8 how can I do the same in a hook?

For example, this loads my first value of a field:

```
$a_id = $adress->field_a->target_id;
```

In this case an entity reference field.
But there are more target_ids.

So how to take them?

Comment: `$adress->field_a` should be iterable..so `foreach ($address->field_a as $item)`?

Comment: Yes indeed, that's correct. I think I need a long time for d8! Tanks a lot!

Comment: @Clive you should add that as the answer :) You need the points! ;)

Comment: @Berdir Shhh I'm trying to let someone else answer it so maybe _they_ get the points...these things are heavy ;)

Answer (score 5):

Entity reference fields have a method called `referencedEntities()`.

Usage example:

```
$addresses = $entity->get('address');
foreach($addresses->referencedEntities() as $delta => $address) {
  // Do something with the $address entity
}
```

P.S.
If you only want the field then as [@Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive) mentioned you can just iterate over $addresses.